# Activeadmin set default date

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

When a new record is created I want to set the default date to a month ahead.

With other fields the default is set in the migration, but where would you set it in this situation?

[image]

---

**Update**

I tried to add it to

**models/invoice.rb**

```
 class Invoice < ActiveRecord::Base
 before_create :set_due_date

 private
   def set_due_date
      self.due_date = DateTime.now + 30
   end
 end
```

**admin/invoice.rb**

```
form do |f|
   f.inputs "Options" do
      f.input :due_date, :as => :datepicker
   end
end
```

**Migration**

```
create_table :invoices do |t|
   t.datetime :due_date
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I am understanding correctly, you should be able to add a callback in the Model of whatever the "due_date" field is in.  Something like this maybe:

```
before_create :set_due_date

def set_due_date
  self.due_date = DateTime.now + 30
end
```

Comment: Okay I just tried on a standalone app and it worked for me.  Are you getting an error or is nothing being populated?  Did you restart your server/console?

Comment: It does indeed work. I just didn't notice since it doesn't display the value in the field when creating. But when the record is saved the due date is added correctly. Thanks

Comment: It doesn't display due to using date-picker

Comment: are you using text_field or text_field_tag for the due_date field in your form?

Comment: I updated the question. Think It is a datetime field.

Answer (score 1):

I ended-up using initialize. This caused the value to be set before the page is rendered.

```
after_initialize :set_due_date

 def set_due_date
   self.due_date ||= DateTime.now + 30
 end
```